# How to use JavaScript to get letters pressed on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get only the letters pressed on the keyboard. I've tried to use:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        letter = event.key;
        if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(letter)) {
            console.log(letter);
        }
        
});
```

But the console shows, for instance, when "F12", "Shift", "CapsLock", "ArrowRight" and other non-letter keys are pressed. How can i resolve this?

Comment: This is my first question, and i'm beginning to code, so if I'm doing something wrong or if I should be more specific, please tell me and I'll do my best to improve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use **onkeypress** event.

```js
function myKeyPress(e){
  var keynum;

  if(window.event) { // IE                  
    keynum = e.keyCode;
  } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                 
    keynum = e.which;
  }

  alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
```